# Is there any way to run a script for Windows that allows ping -a from a ping result?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt, ping

Good Morning,

I'm looking for a way to speed up my work with a batch file and I was wondering if anyone can help.  What I'm looking for is a script to run on Command Prompt that will perform a ping on a computer name and then use the resulting ip address of that ping in a ping -a command.

At best all I can think to do is this, despite knowing that it's wrong:

```
@echo off
set /p asset="Enter asset: "
ping %asset%
read result
ping %result%
@pause
```

Any help is gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way of reading the output of a command is `for/f`. Choosing the correct delimiters and the right token gets you exactly what you want:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%i in ('ping -n 1 -4 %asset%') do set result=%%i
```